# Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE issue with Swagger - Swagger-resources not found

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0

I've developed code **Spring Boot v 2.1.3.RELEASE** and **Swagger Version 2.9.2**.

SwaggerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .groupName("Public - Mock")
                .select()
                .apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.boot")))
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
                .globalResponseMessage(
                        RequestMethod.GET,
                        newArrayList(new ResponseMessageBuilder().code(500).message("Error").build()));
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("API")
                .description("API")
                .version("0.1")
                .build();
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Add Log4j2 Dependency -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
<repository>
    <id>swagger</id>
    <name>swagger</name>
    <url>http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local</url>
</repository>
</repositories>

<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

application.properties

```
spring.application.name=API Management
server.servlet.context-path=/api-management/v1
```

When I launch: http://localhost:8080/api-management/v1/swagger-ui.html#

I get below error:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per Swagger github [discussions](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2345#issuecomment-379545440), **Spring boot 2.x isn't supported officially yet.**

However, while waiting for release version, it works with snapshot version from JFrog repositories. I have tried it and it works with Spring Boot 2.1.

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-data-rest</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>JFrog</id>
        <name>JFrog Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Then use `@EnableSwagger2WebMvc` instead of `@EnableSwagger2`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2WebMvc
@Import(SpringDataRestConfiguration.class)
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Above solution is quoted from [here](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2345#issuecomment-493437424) .